# How do I convert a timezone aware string literal into a datetime object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

I have a string from a 3rd party log file that I need to convert into a `datetime` object. The log entry is in the form:

```
... timestamp=datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 25, 15, 59, 21, 410787, tzinfo=tzlocal()), ...
```

I have tried extracting into a tuple/list and using the datetime constructor like this:

```
    timestamp_str = chop(line, 'timestamp=datetime.datetime(', '),')
    timestamp_chunks = timestamp_str.split(', ')
    dt_list = [int(x) for x in timestamp_chunks[0:7]]
```

where `chop` is a utility function I wrote that returns a substring.

I can make a `datetime` by unpacking the tuple/list into the constructor

```
dt = datetime.datetime(*dt_list)
```

This works, but ignores the timezone information.

I tried adding it onto the end:

```
dt_list.append(timestamp_chunks[7])
dt = datetime.datetime(*dt_list)
```

but then I get the error `tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'str'`

I have tried different approaches, like using `dateutil.parser`, but it doesn't help because this isn't in any accepted `strftime` format.

I could do some funky math to figure out the unix epoch, but that still leaves me with the timezone issue.

I was hoping there would be some date utility that would rehydrate a datetime from a string tuple like the one I have in the log - which looks like it is a `repr` or `str` of a `datetime` object

Comment: Do you know the timezone that the logfile comes from? It appears that the string representation you have does not include the timezone that it is created in.

Comment: What else might appear in the log, in the place where this example says `tzinfo=tzlocal()`? What should happen for those possibilities? More importantly, **why** does the log look like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the `datetime` object timezone-aware you can create it with:

`dt = datetime.datetime(*dt_list).astimezone(tz=None)`

This will make `dt` timezone-aware, with the timezone set to the system local timezone. However, this assumes that the timezone of the logfile that you are parsing is the same as yours. If the server timezone isn't saved in the logfile then you can't work it out from the example string you have provided.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the limitation that really exists, namely that there is information missing from the log. For now I am going to make a (reasonably safe) assumption about the timezone of the log. Turns out, though, that there are multiple timezone entries in the log for different parts. For instance the log entry timestamp and that of a detail in the log line can be different. Bad log structure at the end of the day, but it's what I have.